# Images do not display on a static page hosted on AWS S3

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In S3, I have an index.html, a CSS file and an images folder with 3 jpg files in it. I cut and pasted the jpgs into the S3 folder.  They showed as being there. I set a display policy per the instructions to display to everyone.  The page displayed, but the images did not.  I get the alt text and the tooltips, but no images.  On the page, when I right click the Open Image in New Tab, I get an Access Denied message in XML.  The page is:   http://s3.amazonaws.com/pittsfordcommunitycenter/index.html

Images display on my development PC. I've tried a lot of things in AWS, including what the documentation suggested.  What do I need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your index.html URL:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/pittsfordcommunitycenter/index.html
```

This is your first image URL, which is missing the bucket name:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/images/WheelchairInElevator_w_475.jpg
```

The image URL should actually be:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/pittsfordcommunitycenter/images/WheelchairInElevator_w_475.jpg
```

Viewing your page source it looks like, given the location of your index.html file, all your image paths should start with `./images/` instead of `../images/`. Since it works on your local machine I'm guessing your local index.html location is different, relative to the image files.

Comment: Yes, ./images/ works both on my development PC and in AWS.  Thanks. I also appreciate that you described your problem solving approach - teaching one to fish.

Answer (score 2):

AWS domain links are case sensitive unlike you local machine.
In AWS S3 static Webhosting

```
../images/WHEELCHAIRINELEVATOR_W_475.JPG is **NOT EQUAL** to
../images/wheelchairinelevator_w_475.jpg
```